# How to fill an Array from List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

i have a Controller

```
namespace WebForms
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

public class ProductsController : ApiController
{

    Product[] products = new Product[] 
    { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
    };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public Product GetProductById(int id)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return product;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategory(string category)
    {
        return products.Where(
            (p) => string.Equals(p.Category, category,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
}
```

i want to fill the array Products from db.

i have a class Product.
in my code a use Extension method to fill a list

```
List<Product> myProducts = new List<Product>();
myProducts.FillData();
```

where i need to put that code to fill the array with the list?

Comment: You want to convert to contents of the list into an array?

Comment: Or are you asking how to implement and call a custom extension method?

Comment: use the `List<T>.ToArray()` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx

Comment: @TYH , yes i think that this is my question.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311042.aspx For your future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't resize an array, so in any case you'll need to create new one.

So using [Enumerable.ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) on your `myProducts` should be fine:

```
  products = myProducts.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other comments and the answer to simply call `.ToArray()` and end it. But since the OP was interested in custom extension methods...

Create a new namespace above like so which contains the logic of your extension method.

```
namespace CustomExtensions
{
    public static class ListExtension
    {
        public static void Fill(this List<object> thing) //Must be "this" followed by the type of object you want to extend
        {
            //Whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Next add `using CustomExtensions` in the namespace of where you are doing the work. Now when you write...

```
var myList = new List<object>();
myList.Fill()
```

The compiler should not complain. Again this is not the ideal solution since what you are asking for is built in already.